# I'm able to ping the instances, but when I run the ansible playbook it's getting failed on the instances

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

The ad-hoc `ansible` command runs without any error:

```
suchetla@xhdlc210320:/scratch$ ansible all -m ping -i /opt/hosts
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details
xhdlc201168 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
xhdlc201164 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
xhdlc201166 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

But `ansible-playbook` command fails:

```
suchetla@xhdlc210320:/scratch$ ansible-playbook -i /opt/hosts mars.yml
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details
Sudo password:

PLAY [xhd-hosts] ***************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [xhdlc210319]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"ansible.legacy.setup": {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to xhdlc210319 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\n/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/home/suchetla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1711451084.9141061-329683-269580434256761/AnsiballZ_setup.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 2}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"}
```

Below is my `playbook.yml`:

```yaml
---
- hosts: xhd-hosts
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_exe: "/tools/xgs/bin/sudo"
  #become_exe: "sudo"
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "ansible_sudo_pass"
      prompt: "Sudo password"
      private: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install Prometheus Node Exporter
      apt:
        name: device-tree-compiler
        state: present
```

My inventory is in `/opt/hosts`:

```ini
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
```

I created a public key on the ansible installed instance and copied on to the authorized keys on the destination servers.

Comment: This is how I run the playbook.yml                                                                                  
 ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i /opt/hosts Then it prompts me for the password

Comment: suchetla@xhdlc210320:/scratch$ ls -alh
total 7.5G
drwxrwxrwt  7 root     root              4.0K Mar 26 16:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 ubuntu   ubuntu            4.0K Feb 22  2019 gcc-8.3.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root              109M Feb 22  2019 gcc-8.3.0.tar.gz
drwx------  2 root     root               16K Nov 20 21:25 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root               340 Mar 26 16:34 mars.yml
mars.yml is my playbook, how can I run my playbook with my user i.e., suchetla or do I need to switch to a root user

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logs, your problem is not related to the Network, but to your Filesystem permissions!

This line:

`/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/home/suchetla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1711451084.9141061-329683-269580434256761/AnsiballZ_setup.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Please check the path and see if there are any specific permission issues, or update your question with `ls -alh`